# Log-in button element **{class="d-button-label"}** is not available in "response.text" content

Tags: python, python-requests

I made a simple python program to get a webpage content using 'get' method and display it on browser. Pls look at the code,

```
import requests


def main():
    url = 'https://forums.whonix.org/'

    with requests.Session() as s:
        resp = s.get(url=url)

    with open("home_page.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(resp.text)

    print(resp.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I **inspected** the live web-page and found the log-in button in **class="d-button-label"** available. But the same is not available in downloaded **home_page.html** file.

I plan to use this button **class="d-button-label"** to automate the log in process.

Kindly help me how should proceed further

Answer (score 0):

Sites tend to send different html to requests that are not from browsers, you can simulate you're in a browser using headers. Try this:

```
import requests


def main():
    url = 'https://forums.whonix.org/'

    headers = { 
        'Host': 'forums.whonix.org',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }   

    with requests.Session() as s:
        resp = s.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    with open("home_page.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(resp.text)

    print(resp.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried with header also. Still the result is same.

Comment: When I tested here it changed the html to the same as the browser, maybe ehat you want have a different class. Here the Log in button have the `class=btn btn-primary btn-small login-button btn-icon-text`